# Python package to handle data change event

Tags: python

I have a requirement that need to respond to data change and send the updated data by graphql subscription (based on websocket) to browser. The data change event is triggered by kafka.

I just jumped to Python from Javascript. In nodejs, it quite easy. I can use [this NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) to respond to event. 
The javascript code looks like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events')

var ee = new EventEmitter()
ee.on('message', function (text) {
  console.log(text)
})
ee.emit('message', 'hello world')
```

I explored a bit about [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY), but this seems a bit still in progress and big. 
My question is, in Python how do I react to a data change event? Any mature package or code pattern for handling this?